# How to subtract between two list every 5 elements in Python?

Tags: python

I have two lists

> `A = [3.8, 749.6334444641317, 7.8, 10.6, 7.4]`

> `B = [1.0, 500.45288168429073, 3.0, 16.0, 4.0, 6.0, 1107.40562842779, 8.0, 6.0, 5.0, 0.0, 109.73034003937472, 12.0, 5.0, 10.0, 0.0, 457.73923699552466, 8.0, 9.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.392471135139845, 2.0, 14.0, 3.0]`

How do I subtract B - A for every 5 elements in B,
with the result supporting decimal numbers?

e.g

```
1.0 - 3.8

500.45288168429073 - 749.6334444641317

3.0 - 7.8

16.0 - 10.6 

4.0 - 7.4
```

and repeat

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "every fifth element".  A only has five elements -- do you mean every fifth element of both lists, or only every fifth element of B?  And once the subtraction is done, where should the result go?  Do you want the elements in B to be _updated_ with the result of the subtraction?

Comment: For every fifth element of B, results should either be updated in B or be in a new list

Comment: Your examples are even more confusing.  First, they are `A - B`, not `B - A` as stated in the question.  Second, it's even less clear what you mean by "every fifth element". 
 The phrase "every fifth element" generally means that you would skip the first four elements, pick the fifth one, skip the next four, pick the tenth, and so on.  Those examples do not skip anything.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, have edited hopefully to show a little more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat A, and then zip it with B.

```
from itertools import cycle

A = [3.8, 749.6334444641317, 7.8, 10.6, 7.4]
B = [1.0, 500.45288168429073, 3.0, 16.0, 4.0, 6.0, 1107.40562842779, 8.0, 6.0, 5.0, 0.0, 109.73034003937472, 12.0, 5.0, 10.0, 0.0, 457.73923699552466, 8.0, 9.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.392471135139845, 2.0, 14.0, 3.0]

[a - b for a, b in zip(cycle(A), B)]
```

Resuts in :

```
[2.8,                 # 3.8 - 1.0
 249.18056277984095,  # 749.6334444641317 - 500.45288168429073
 4.8,                 #  ...
 -5.4,
 ... 
 -3.4,                # 10.6 - 14.0
 4.4]                 # 7.4 - 3
```

---

**EDIT**:

With the change in the question you can simply swap a and b:

```
[b - a for a, b in zip(cycle(A), B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` with list slicing:

```
C = [y-x for x,y in zip(A,B[::5])]
print(C)
```